# using while loop for determining square roots of numbers c++

Tags: c++, while-loop, sqrt

I am running a c++ program, using while loop for determining square roots of numbers, here i have defined variables, tried but nothings seems to work for me, any hand would be great to assist me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int n=10, N=0, i=0;

 while(i<5)
 N=i*n;
 cout<<"numbers ="<<"\t Square root="<<sqrt(N)<<endl;
 return 0;      
}
```

The program execute successfully but nothing display (emptyb line). thanks.

Comment: What do you expect this program to do? Can you describe what each line does in your own words? Do you know what it should do? HINT: in this form the program doesn't even terminate, the `i<5` is always true.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is a debugger, not a plea for help on SO. Read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: After `for` and `while` you should enclose your loop in curly brackets {}. Here your loop consists of one line: `N=i*n;` Also, what @riodoro1 says.

Comment: its not clear which part of your code should be inside the loop. You know that you will iterate 5 times, so therefore use a for loop.

Comment: `while (i < 5) N = i*n;` is an infinite loop, since `i` is zero, and is never changed.   The statement writing to `cout` is AFTER the infinite loop, so is never reached.

Comment: Thanks, i have corrected that, sure it's an infinite loop

Comment: Thanks your ideas does work

Answer (score 0):

```
while(i<5)
N=i*n;
```

Because you didn't indent or use brackets, you may have missed this and is equal to:

```
while (i < 5) {
    N = i * n;
}
```

because the language specifies that no brackets means you just apply it to the next statement only and keep looping on that.

So this just loops forever as `i` never grows beyond 5 to exit the loop.

Comment: Thanks, your idea rock

Answer (score 0):

Just add fancy brackets to your loop and check where you want to change i and n.